# Adaptive Updates In Vowpal Wabbit Formula

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am looking at the following 2 presentations about the updates done by VW when the --adaptive flag is used. It *seems* these are different.

1. http://www.slideshare.net/jakehofman/technical-tricks-of-vowpal-wabbit
2. https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/v6.1_tutorial.pdf

With these two descriptions (respectively):

#1

[image]

#2

[image]

My questions:

1. Which of these are correct (or are they the same)?
2. For number 1 it appears that the gradient from the t+1 example is used in the denominator. How is this done? Does this mean that the new weight (labeled w_i) is the weight for example t+1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, the [first presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/jakehofman/technical-tricks-of-vowpal-wabbit) contains an error/typo in the AdaGrad formula. The formula [should be](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse547/14wi/slides/logistic-SGD-adagrad-annotated2.pdf#page=7) w_{i, t+1} := w_{i, t} - (\eta * g_{i, t} / \sqrt{sum}), where sum=\sum_{t'=1}^t g_{i, t'}^2.

In VowpalWabbit, `--adaptive` (corresponding to the AdaGrad idea) is on by default. But `--normalized` and `--invariant` are also on by default, which means that on top of plain AdaGrad few more tricks/improvements are applied. The interaction of all these tricks is complex and there is no single slide which describes all the aspects, so the only reference is the source code ([gd.cc](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/vowpalwabbit/gd.cc)).

> Which of these are correct (or are they the same)?

I think they are not same, but they are different "layers" of the complex code. I think that the slide 33 (which you cite as #2) of the [second presentation](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/v6.1_tutorial.pdf) corresponds to the slide 31 (which you don't cite) of the 
[first presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/jakehofman/technical-tricks-of-vowpal-wabbit), but I am not sure.

Comment: It is a very confusing set up. Does --sgd set it to the update on slide 11 of #2 above? So that then --adaptive is really --adaptive=TRUE meaning this gets turns on which changes slide 11 in some way? Same for the other two flags (--normalized and --invariant).